# Spawning Actor from array of classes UE5

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I'm attempting to use SpawnActor() to spawn random actors from an array of classes. I've spent several years using UE4/UE5 blueprints, but this is my first time working in cpp in a long time. The trouble I'm running into is with the SpawnActor function, maybe I'm hooking up the parameters wrong.

Below is the code for my spawning logic in my cpp file:

```
void ADS_Generator::SpawnFlora()
{
    FHitResult CurrentHit;
    FActorSpawnParameters SpawnInfo;

    for (int F = 0; F < FloraIterations; ++F)
    {
        if (SpawnedFlora.Num() <= MaxFlora)
        {
            CurrentHit = SpawnLineTrace(Vertices[FMath::RandRange(0, Vertices.Num() - 1)]);
            if (CurrentHit.bBlockingHit == true)
            {
                if (FMath::RandRange(1, 100) >= FloraTolerance)
                {
                    AActor* CurrentFlora = GetWorld()->SpawnActor(Flora[0], CurrentHit.ImpactPoint, FVector(0, 0, FMath::RandRange(-180, 180)), SpawnInfo);
                    SpawnedFlora.Add(CurrentFlora);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the code for my header file where I declare the array of actor classes:

```
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
TArray<TSubclassOf<class AActor>> Flora;
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
TArray<TSubclassOf<class AActor>> Fauna;
```

The specific error I'm getting is this:

```
"C++ no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list
            argument types are: (TSubclassOf<AActor>, FVector_NetQuantize, FVector, FActorSpawnParameters)
            object type is: UWorld"
```

I've tried adding "::StaticClass()" as well as using "->StaticClass" to no avail.

Any thoughts or advice? I definitely need to watch some videos and brush up on my cpp, I'm very rusty.
Note: I'm using Flora[0] as a placeholder instead of randomizing the array index just to test.

Comment: What's the specific problem you're running into with that code?

Comment: Sorry about that, I haven't posted much on here so I fumbled. I edited the post with a link to the error image.

It seems my parameters for the spawning function are incorrect, and I don't completely understand why. I've tried adding "::StaticClass()" as well as using "->StaticClass" to no avail.

Comment: No images of plain text here please! Post the verbatim error message appropriately formatted in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue! The problem was my Rotation was defined as a plain FVector, but it needed to be converted to a rotation and then a quaternion, respectively. Below is the code, but fixed:

```
void ADS_Generator::SpawnFlora()
{
    FHitResult CurrentHit;
    FActorSpawnParameters SpawnInfo;

    for (int F = 0; F < FloraIterations; ++F)
    {
        if (SpawnedFlora.Num() <= MaxFlora)
        {
            CurrentHit = SpawnLineTrace(Vertices[FMath::RandRange(0, Vertices.Num() - 1)]);
            if (CurrentHit.bBlockingHit == true)
            {
                UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("HIT!"));
                if (FMath::RandRange(1, 100) >= FloraTolerance)
                {
                    FTransform SpawnLoc;
                    SpawnLoc.SetLocation(CurrentHit.ImpactPoint);
                    SpawnLoc.SetRotation((FVector(0, 0, FMath::RandRange(-180, 180)).Rotation().Quaternion()));
                    SpawnLoc.SetScale3D(FVector(1, 1, 1));
                    AActor* CurrentFlora = GetWorld()->SpawnActor<AActor>(Flora[0]->StaticClass(), SpawnLoc, SpawnInfo);
                    SpawnedFlora.Add(CurrentFlora);
                    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Spawned Flora!"));
                }
            }
            else if(CurrentHit.bBlockingHit == false)
            {
                UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("NO HIT"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

TLDR; Locations and Rotations are stored differently and I totally forgot.

Comment: If you want to make your code more descriptive, you can also use [FQuat::MakeFromEuler](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/API/Runtime/Core/Math/FQuat/MakeFromEuler/) instead of doing two chained conversions.